# video.js not playing in chrome when stay at other tab

Tags: video.js

As title, my website is using html 5 video [videojs.com](http://videojs.com) to play video.
It works fine in chrome, fire fox. But it does not auto play when I use other tab.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand when you say "when I use other tab", however if you wish to auto play you have to use the attribute **autoplay** like this:

```
<video id='last' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls preload='metadata' autoplay  > <source src='../videos/P04A.mp4' type='video/mp4'> <source src='http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm' type='video/webm'>
```

PS: I post as a response because I can't comment (you know reputation and all...), but I will edit as soon as you specify